# Freezing and resuming execution using SpiderMonkey debug API

Tags: firebug, firefox-addon-sdk, npapi, spidermonkey

I want to implement my own GWT plugin for Firefox, and I have one problem. Consider, we have a function that causes program to suspend until remote debugger, running on IDE, says "ok, you can continue". AFAIK, this was possible with old NPAPI, at least the old plugin used NPAPI. I guess that is was capable of doing synchronous socket I/O. Now NPAPI is deprecated, and GWT plugin does not work. As an alternative I found [JS Debugger API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JS_Debugger_API_Guide) and I hope it could help. Unfortunately, documentation is very poor. I tried to learn Firebug, since I suppose that it uses debug API, but I failed to understand anything. What I really need is to freeze execution when it reaches some function call and signal somewhere. Then I need to signal back to Firefox to resume execution. Does debugger API allows to do it? If it does, where can I find code snippets for the described goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug, even in 2.0, mostly doesn't use the Debugger API directly, instead it communicates using the [Remote Debugging Protocol](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Remote_Debugging_Protocol) (RDP), which definitely sounds like it could be a good option for you.

If you want to do things more manually, take a look at the [implementation of the RDP backend](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/toolkit/devtools/server/actors/script.js). In particular, pausing/resuming execution (which there is no explicit support for in the Debugger API) is done through nested event loops.

Comment: Simon, thank you for the answer, it is likely what I looked for. But I still don't understand how to use this protocol. Does Firefox expose it by default on some port, or should I start it with a certain command line switches. Also I tried to learn code that you posted, and found, that nested event loops are implemented with `EventLoop`/`EventLoopStack`, which use mysterious `xpcInspector`. And I also found how it is created `this.xpcInspector = require("xpcInspector");`. And I really got stuck with it.

Comment: TBH I don't really know how to connect to the protocol. I suspect there will be two different ways: one from within process (look in maybe bti/ and chrome/tabWatcher in Firebug master for examples, or at devtools), one from another process (which will require ports etc. and probably some pref set - the Browser Debugger uses it). I guess you'll just have to search code or ask someone who knows more (e.g. Jan Odvarko, or #devtools). xpcInspector is defined at http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/e86a0d92d174/toolkit/devtools/Loader.jsm#l33 (dxr can help with these sorts of questions).